# Equivalent of the CMS Directive {{media url="..."}} in Normal Block Templates

Tags: blocks, cms, url, media

What is the equivalent of `{{media url="wysiwyg/image.jpg"}}` which can be used in CMS pages if we want to use this in a normal `.phtml` file (of the type `core/template`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rendering of this such URLs is done when displaying CMS pages or blocks in

`\Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::mediaDirective`:

```
public function mediaDirective($construction)
{
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $params['url'];
}
```

Base on this code, just an

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') ?>image.jpg">
```

can be used in the template

Comment: Just remove the blockquote(`\``) from the second code snippet (after `?>image.jpg">`). (I can't edit less than 6 letters)

Comment: +1 But it may be better to pass `Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA` instead of `'media'`?

Answer (score 12):

In a phtml template file:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $url;
```

In a CMS block or page:

```
{{store direct_url="media/url"}}
```

The difference between `{{media url="foo"}}` and `{{store direct_url="media/foo"}}` is that the latter hardcodes the media directory path as `media`.
That might lead to issues when using a CDN or something, because it bypasses `Mage::getBaseUrl('media')`.

Comment: what is the difference between `{{store direct_url="media/url"}}` and `{{media url="foo"}}` ?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I also edited my question to make it more clear - I want the full URL of a picture. Actually I would be happy to accept my own answer ;-) --- as I know my problem best :-P

Comment: Note that: {{store direct_url="media/url"}} -> If mod_rewrite is disabled, this may introduce the index.php in the url, hence breaking the media url.

Comment: @MagePsycho: good point. Lucky I've never had ha store with mod_rewrite disabled.